# How to add method to an existing class just like Objective-C category in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, objective-c-category

As far as I remember Ruby also has this feature. Adding a method to an existing class dynamically. But I forgot how to do this.  What is the feature's name and how to do that?

Comment: How is this not a real question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add a method to an existing class, you just reopen the class and define the method.

```
class ExistingClass
  def new_method
    ...
  end
end
```

You could also use `class_eval`:

```
ExistingClass.class_eval do
  def new_method
    ...
  end
end
```

All your instances of `ExistingClass` will gain the new functionality of `new_method`.